# VBS Microsoft.XMLHTTP status

Tags: vbscript, status, xmlhttprequest

Why does the following code give a 80004005 error when run? I'm trying to get the status of several sites every 10 seconds...(the ones given are examples).

```
'http://www.sebsworld.net/information/?page=VBScript-URL
'http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/xmlhttp.htm

'the array of sites
sites = Array("http://www.google.com/","http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")

While(True)
    For Each site In sites

        'Get site status
        Set Http = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        Http.Open "GET", site, True
        Http.Send

        If(Http.Status <> 200) Then 'site isn't 200
            MsgBox "The site at " & vbNewLine & site & vbNewLine & "has status: " & Http.Status
        End If
    Next

    WScript.Sleep(10)'Sleep 10 seconds
Wend
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you have to change

```
Http.Open "GET", site, True
```

to

```
Http.Open "GET", site, False
```

because you cannot use `Http.Status` immediately after `Http.Send` if the call is asynchronous.

Furthermore, you shoud use

```
Set Http = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

instead of

```
Set Http = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
```

because the normal XMLHTTP object has problems with redirected web sites (www.google.com normally redirects you to another site).

Comment: (should also be 10000 for 10 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

```
Const ForWriting = 2

strURL="http://asithayomal.1apps.com"
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 
Call objHTTP.Open("GET", strURL, FALSE) 
objHTTP.Send

msgbox objHTTP.ResponseText
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.